# Creating a map for millions of objects in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have an abstract class called `Object` that has a few virtual functions, one of which is a function that will retrieve the `id` of an `Object`.

Currently, I am using a `std::vector<Object>` to store tens of millions of these objects. Unfortunately, adding, copying, or removing from this is painfully slow.

I wanted to create a hash map that could maybe have the `Object->id` as the key, and maybe the object itself as a value? Or is there some type of data structure that would allow for easy insertion and removal like a `std::vector` but would be faster for tens of millions of objects?

I would want the class to end up looking something like this outline:

```
stl::container<Objects*> obj_container;

DataContainer::DataContainer()
    : stl::container(initialized_here)
{}

DataContainer::addObject(Object* object)
{
    obj_container.insert(object);
}

DataContainer::removeObject(Object* object)
{
    obj_container.remove(object);
}

DataContainer::preSort()
{
     obj_container.sort_by_id();
}

DataContainer::getObject(Object* object)
{
    if(!obj_container.contains(object)) { return; }
    binary_search(object);
}
```

Is there anything really fast at processing large amounts of these objects, or is there anything really fast that could possibly use an unsigned integer id from an object to process the data?

Also, my class would get pre-sorted, so every object would be sorted by ID before being added to the container. Then I would do a binary search on the data by ID.

Comment: You can use `std::dequeue` or normal `std::map` and then profile. BTW you can also use `std::set` with custom equal and less functions that operate only on IDs.

Comment: `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` would seem the obvious options. They have different performance specifications for some operations so you may want to research to determine which would suit your application best.

Comment: There are a lot of associative structures available. The standard library has `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.  Boost provides `boost::flat_map`. You will have to profile and see which ones best for your application.

Comment: Note that if you have performance problems with `std::unordered_map` out of the box, you may have to think hard about the Hash used. So before doing that, it's usually easier to try plain `std::map` and see if that suffices. But frankly any of these is _way_ faster than removing from the middle of a `std::vector`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were clearer about your requirements. Do you need to find objects by their key? Are you doing a linear search for that? Do you need to be able to delete arbitrary objects? All these questions will condition the datastructure which you use.

Comment: @rici I should have been more clear, sorry about that. I need to find objects by id. I can pre-sort the data by id as well, so I would use a binary search on these objects by their id.

Comment: `unordered_map` is what is usually meant by "hash map". `map` is a search tree.

Comment: @alex: Cool. Presorting won't help if you need to be able to delete arbitrary objects, so an `unordered_map`  is probably a good option. But please edit your question to make the requirements clearer. Most people won't read the comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could use [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (if the `id`-s have some order and are unique for it) or [std::unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and I would suggest you make it a component of your container, not derive your container from it. You'll better have a way of constructing a local fake `Object` with only its `id` ...

```
class Object {
   friend class BigContainer;
   unsigned long _id;
   // other fields;
   // your constructors
  public:
    unsigned long id() const { return _id; };
  private:
   Object(unsigned long pseudoid); // construct a fake object
};

struct LessById {
  bool operator () (const Object &ob1, const Object& ob2) 
    { return ob1.id() < ob2.id(); };
  bool operator () (const Object &ob, unsigned long idl)
    { return ob1.id() < idl;
};

class BigContainer {
   std::set<Object,LessById> set;
public:
   // add members, constructors, destructors, etc...
   bool contains(unsigned long id) const {
     Object fakeobj{id};
     if (set.find(fakeobj) != set.end()) return true;
     return false;
   };
   const Object* find_by_id(unsigned long id) const {
     Object fakeobj{id};
     auto p = set.find(fakeobj);
     if (p != set.end()) return &(*p);
     return nullptr;
   };

   bool contains(const Object& ob) const {
      if (set.find(ob) != set.end()) return true;
      return false;
   };
   void add(const Object&ob) const {
     Object fakeobj{id};
     auto p = set.find(fakeobj);
     if (p == set.end()) set.insert(ob);
   }
   void remove(unsigned long id) const {
     Object fakeobj{id};
     auto p = set.find(fakeobj);
     if (p != set.end()) set.erase(p);
   }
};
```

If you want a set of *pointers* use a set of some [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) and adapt the scheme above.

If the `Object` is big and you have trouble in defining a way of constructing efficiently local fake objects for a given id, define a super `struct BoxedId { unsigned long id; BoxedId(unsigned long l): id(l) {}; }`, declare internally a `std::set<std::shared_ptr<BoxedId>,BoxedLessById>` make `class Object : public BoxedId`, etc...

BTW, since `Object` has `virtual` methods you probably will subclass it and you need to have a set of pointers. You need to define a pointer policy (are every actual instances of sub-classes of `Object`-s in your `Container`) and use some smart pointer.... You need to define who is in charge of `delete`-ing your `Object`-s (who *owns* the pointer). Is it *only* the unique `BigContainer`.

Read the [C++11 rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this site : http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-summary.html

It shows the time complexity of each operation of each STL.

First be clear about your requirement and then choose particular STL wisely by comparing its time complexity shown in above link.